# Javascript - Why no recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, constructor

Recursion is not happening? Can anyone point out why?

```
function a() {
console.log("xx");
console.log(this);
a();
}
var a2 = new a();
```

Comment: Your edit **completely** changes the question, and if you tried it, you'd find that you would indeed get infinite recursion doing that. It's not appropriate to fundamentally change questions once they've been answered, I recommend using the "rollback" feature to return to the original text.

Answer (score 6):

### Answer to the updated question:

Your update to the question **completely changes it**. The new code will indeed recurse forever:

```js
var counter = 0;
function a() {
  snippet.log(counter);
  if (++counter < 10) {  // To avoid recursing forever
    a();
  }
}
var a2 = new a();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

### Answer to the *original* question:

> Recursion is not happening? Can anyone point out why?
>
> ```
> function a() {
> console.log("xx");
> console.log(this);
> Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor(); //Isn't this a recursive call?
> }
> var a2 = new a();
> ```

It *is* a recursive call, but the recursion stops after just one recursive call because this line:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor();
```

...calls `a` with `this` set to the global object (because you're using loose mode*), not set to the instance. So on the next call, `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` returns `Object.prototype`, and calls `Object()`.

If you changed it to

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.call(this);
```

**then** it would recurse forever (so I've added a counter to the following so it doesn't do that), because we're calling `constructor` and setting `this` to be the same as the current `this`, so the next call will use `a` again, and again, and again...

```js
var counter = 0;
function a() {
  snippet.log(counter);
  if (++counter < 10) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.call(this);
  }
}
var a2 = new a();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

* "because you're using loose mode" - I know this because if you were using strict mode, `this` would be `undefined`, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(undefined)` would throw an error.

---

Side note:

I don't think it's the point of your question (at all), but: You can't really rely on the `constructor` property in the wild. While the JavaScript specification defines that the object created for normal functions and assigned to their `prototype` property will have a `constructor` property pointing back to the function, that's the sum total of what the specification says about `constructor`. Nothing in the specification *uses* that property for anything. I mention this because it's quite common for people to **break** that link, by doing this:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype = {
    something: function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

At that point, `Foo.prototype`'s `constructor` property refers to `Object`, not `Foo`.

If you're only working with your own code, and you don't break `constructor`, you're fine. Sadly, though, it's common to see it being broken in this way.